# On covering with Idoneal integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-forms, binary-quadratic-forms

$d\in\Bbb N$ is an idoneal integer if $N\in\Bbb N_{>1}$ can be written uniquely as $N=x^2\pm dy^2$ then $N=2^mp^n$ where $p$ is odd prime and $n\geq0$ and $m\geq0$ holds.

Let the $65$ known idoneal integers be $d_1,\dots,d_{65}$. Let set of primes that can be represented by $d_i$ be $\mathcal P_i$.

Is there an $N_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $$\bigcup_{i\in\{1,\dots,65\}}\mathcal P_i$$ contain all the primes above $N_0$?

If not what classes of primes are missed out?

Comment: For each $d_i$ pick a prime factor $p_i$ and choose a quadratic non-residue class $\pmod {p_i}$ (if two of the $p_i$ are the same, use the same quadratic non-residue).  Now use the Chinese Remainder Theorem and Dirichlet's theorem.